# PHP - array to json with specific index/key

Tags: php, arrays, json

I received an array and would like to convert it to json by using json_encode in PHP with specific index/key. Array result:

```
{"StatusCode": "2800",
 "card": {
 "studentcard": {
 "1000": [
{
 "Name": "Jerome",
 "CardNumber": "512314512312",
 "CardExpiry": "2017-03-24",
 "CardType": "Library",
},
{
 "Name": "Jerome",
 "CardNumber": "512314512312-b",
 "CardExpiry": "2017-10-22",
 "CardType": "IT",
}],
"1001": [
{
 "Name": "Jason",
 "CardNumber": "512314512313",
 "CardExpiry": "2017-10-22",
 "CardType": "Library",
}]
}
```

Expected result in JSON

```
[
 {
  "Name": "Jerome",
  "CardNumber": "512314512312",
  "CardExpiry": "2017-03-24",
  "CardType": "Library"
 },
 {
  "Name": "Jerome",
  "CardNumber": "512314512312-b",
  "CardExpiry": "2017-10-22",
  "CardType": "IT"
 },
 {
  "Name": "Jason",
  "CardNumber": "512314512313",
  "CardExpiry": "2017-10-22",
  "CardType": "Library"
 }
]
```

How can i remove StatusCode, card, studentcard, 1000 and encode it into expected result in JSON?

Comment: the initial json is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flatten that array with `call_user_func_array('array_merge', ...)`:

```
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $obj["card"]["studentcard"]);
$json = json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/755434) or [repl.it](https://repl.it/GXlx).

Note that in JSON you cannot have a comma after the last property of an object (i.e. just before the closing brace). Also, you had two closing braces missing.

Comment: Your solution works like charm. Never think about it. Thank for correction for json format. Edited

Answer (score 0):

The solution for a ***valid*** JSON string using `json_decode` and `array_merge` functions:

```
$json_str = '{
    "StatusCode": "2800",
    "card": {
        "studentcard": {
            "1000": [{
                "Name": "Jerome",
                "CardNumber": "512314512312",
                "CardExpiry": "2017-03-24",
                "CardType": "Library"
            }, {
                "Name": "Jerome",
                "CardNumber": "512314512312-b",
                "CardExpiry": "2017-10-22",
                "CardType": "IT"
            }],
            "1001": [{
                "Name": "Jason",
                "CardNumber": "512314512313",
                "CardExpiry": "2017-10-22",
                "CardType": "Library"
            }]
        }
    }
}';

$data = json_decode($json_str, true);
$data = array_merge($data["card"]["studentcard"]["1000"], $data["card"]["studentcard"]["1001"]);
$json = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

echo $json;
```

The output:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Jerome",
        "CardNumber": "512314512312",
        "CardExpiry": "2017-03-24",
        "CardType": "Library"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Jerome",
        "CardNumber": "512314512312-b",
        "CardExpiry": "2017-10-22",
        "CardType": "IT"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Jason",
        "CardNumber": "512314512313",
        "CardExpiry": "2017-10-22",
        "CardType": "Library"
    }
]
```

Comment: It's just a wild guess, but he probably needs a solution that doesn't hard-code `1000` and `1001`, and works with more than two elements in `studentcard`.